# Can I make gluten free crepes?

Tags: gluten-free, pancakes

I have seen recipes for gluten free American style pancakes, and suppose that they turn out OK as long as they contain something which keeps them from falling apart. But I was wondering if I can make gluten free palatschinken or crepes. I am reluctant to just use some gluten replacement like starch and non-wheat flours, because it won't bind the crepe together. And I want the result to be like a real crepe - very thin, and flexible enough to be rolled.

Does anybody have experience with gluten-free crepes? Do they work? If yes, how are they made, what should I pay attention to?

Comment: Don't forget to participate in our gluten-free contest! See the Community bulletin for more detail.

Comment: Did you actually intend to remind yourself to participate in the gluten-free contest? ;=)

Comment: @rob I intend to increase visibility for the contest - I am not eligible for a prize, because I won two weeks ago. But if I get ideas for an interesting recipe to try, I will try it.

Comment: I don't know *how* but I know the answer is *yes*: last week I ate a gluten-free Dutch-style pancake at a Dutch pancake restaurant. Like any Dutch pancake, it was thin and rollable (not quite crepe-thin, but maybe 1.5 times as thick, and it didn't seem like making the batter thinner would have been a problem).

Comment: I would be really surprised if a gluten-free flour substitute didn't work. I know that it works for things like brownies, and that crêpes don't really have much gluten development. I've never tried it myself, though.

Answer (score 4):

I thought that crepes (and tasty pancakes) were traditionally made with buckwheat flour. Crepes in particular because buckwheat makes a finer flour. So, traditionally made crepes would be gluten free.

Answer (score 1):

In south India we have a variation of the crepe called a dosa. The dosa batter is made of rice and lentils, thereby gluten free.

You can buy the batter in an indian store nearby, or make it yourself using a blender/grinder.

The dosa is usually savory, so I think it would work best as a savory crepe, though you can try it with fruit, sugar etc .

http://chefinyou.com/2010/03/plain-dosa-recipe/

Comment: I suspect that if you removed any savory seasonings (e.g. the fenugreek) it would work fine with sweet things - rice certainly does, and lentils aren't terribly strongly flavored.

Answer (score 1):

I grew up in Quebec, needless to say I know about crepes. My mother taught me how to cook them at a young age.

My fiancee is celiac so gluten isn't a part of our kitchen at all. I've been able to cook her everything that I would normally make with the exception of a few things. Up until last week crepes were one of them.

I've tried using several all purpose gluten free flours and none did the trick, the crepe would just fall apart in the pan. Even adding `Xanthan Gum` didn't work.

The answer is rice flour. These crepes are a thicker in consistency then a white wheat flour crepe, but with a little bit of butter and maple syrup I enjoy them (and my fiancee loves them).

---

### Ingredients

- 2 eggs
- 2 cups rice flour
- 2 cups milk
- 1/4 tbsp melted butter for each crepe
- 1/4 tbsp olive oil

### Instructions

1. Mix all the ingredients except oil with a fork until smooth.
2. Heat a **non stick** pan and pour 1/4 tbsp butter and 1/4 tbsp oil in it. `The oil will allow the butter to be heated to an even higher temperature then you normally could without burning the butter`
3. When the oil/butter mixture is very hot pour a ladle of batter on the same point in the pan and roll the pan from side to side to give the batter a round shape.
4. Cook it for 1 or 2 minutes. Just check the bottom with a wooden spatula when it releases and flip when it has the nice color you want.
5. Flip it up and cook the other side for 1 or 2 minutes and transfer it on a plate.
6. Repeat the same steps until you finish all the batter pouring 1/4 tbsp olive oil, and 1/4 tbsp butter in the pan each time.
7. Serve these right after you make with various fillings aside. `My favorite is maple syrup with a little extra butter`

Answer (score 1):

Another indian ingredient to look at would be besan (chickpea flour), a batter made from it will hold together on its own or with some rice flour added.